# How can Poisson GLM work with non-count data (rate data)?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, offset

My question is related, but not the same as the following question:  [Fitting a Poisson GLM in R - issues with rates vs. counts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26346/fitting-a-poisson-glm-in-r-issues-with-rates-vs-counts)

Here's some fake data:

```
### some fake data
x=c(1:14)
y=c(0,  1,  2,  3,  1,  4,  9, 18, 23, 31, 20, 25, 37, 45)
y_rate <- y / 1000
```

I'm going to use a Poisson GLM with a log link to predict `y_rate`:

```
### model
pois_mdl <- glm(y_rate ~ x, family=poisson(link="log"))
summary(pois_mdl)
```

Plot the fit:

```
### plot
plot(x, y_rate)
lines(x, pois_mdl$fitted.values)
```

I am surprised that Poisson `glm()` allows for non-integer values in the dependent variable. Draws from a Poisson distribution are always integers (regardless of the value of the mean parameter). Why doesn't `glm()` blow up?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70054/ seems duplicate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know why `glm()` doesn't blow up.  To figure that out, you'll have to unpack all of the underlying code.  (In addition, if your only question is how the R code works, this question is off topic here.)

What I can say is that you are not modeling the rates correctly.  If you want to model [rates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_%28mathematics%29) instead of [counts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_data), you need to include an [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression#.22Exposure.22_and_offset) in the model's formula.  (There is a nice discussion on CV of what an offset is here: [When to use an offset in a Poisson regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11182/7290))  Using your example the code would be:

```
pois_mdl2 <- glm(y~x+offset(log(rep(1000,14))), family=poisson(link="log"))
```

Note that, although the coefficient estimates are the same, the standard errors are quite different:

```
summary(pois_mdl2)$coefficients
#               Estimate Std. Error   z value      Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept) -6.5681214 0.25118701 -26.14833 1.029521e-150
# x            0.2565236 0.02203911  11.63947  2.596237e-31
summary(pois_mdl)$coefficients
#               Estimate Std. Error    z value  Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept) -6.5681214  7.9431516 -0.8268911 0.4082988
# x            0.2565236  0.6969324  0.3680753 0.7128171
```

Answer (score 6):

While I don't recommend looking at the [source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/glm.R) for `glm` for those that wish to preserve their mental health, I looked at the source code to `glm`.  The reason R doesn't blow up seems to be that it just doesn't bother to do the kind of defensive checks it probably should.

The main iteratively re-weighted least squares loop works by using the methods attached to a `family` object of the appropriate type.  In this case, that is `poisson`:

```
> poi <- poisson()
> class(poi)
[1] "family"
```

This family object has all that glm needs to fit the model, for example:

```
> poi$linkfun(1)
[1] 0
> poi$linkinv(1)
[1] 2.718282
```

Another, here's the derivative of the inverse link:

```
> poi$mu.eta(1)
[1] 2.718282
```

The `y` data comes in on line 258:

```
dev <- sum(dev.resids(y, mu, weights))
```

Unfortunately, `dev.resids` could not care at all whether `y` is positive integer valued:

```
> poi$dev.resid(1.5, 1, 1)
[1] 0.2163953
```

So I guess `R` doesn't blow up because it didn't think *to* blow up.

Comment: +1, lol. There was a reason I didn't actually look at the source code myself ;-).

Comment: The check, if there was one, would most likely occur in `poisson()$initialize`, which only checks that the `y`s are non-negative.

Compare it to `binomial()$initialize`, which, along with dealing with the possible one- or two-column specification of `y`, also checks that they are integer-valued.

Comment: Nice @Mark, I missed that.